# 90s Cyberpunk TV Series or Video Game ID: Hooks for surviving subway passage

Tags: story-identification, tv, video-games, cyberpunk

I recall, as a kid in the late 90s, seeing a clip on TV showcasing either a live action TV series, or a video game with full-motion video elements, involving a gritty cyberpunk setting.

The scene took place on a subway platform that had railings with square rings attached to them. People on the platform had handheld hooks with them - either a personal possession or given to them when entering the station - and had to hook onto one of these rings when a train went by (an express, I guess). Because the train was moving so fast, it would suck anyone along with it unless they were secured by using their hook.

I recall the scene involved a confrontation on the platform, I believe between a detective and a suspect, and on several occasions a train would go by with such force that the characters were swept sideways while holding onto their hooks. I think the ending of the confrontation ended with someone losing their hook and getting sucked in behind the train and off the platform.

I'm not confident of this, but I recalled it was an fmv video game where combat was played via quick-time events, like *Dragon's Lair*. The look and feel reminded me a lot of the film *Blade Runner* or the TV series *Total Recall 2070*. For a long time I thought it was Westwood's *Blade Runner* game, but have since learned it's 3d voxel animation over pre-rendered backgrounds.